# How to check validation for a text is not an email?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have an user input as "text", however people insist on typing their email addresses to that input.

Is there a way to prevent people typing their email address with HTML5 or any other way?

This code checks if the input is an email, I need the opposite plus input type text.

Also I have to Set custom validation message if possible.

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This is how I will use it with custom validation message

```html
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" pattern="THIS IS THE PATTERN I AM LOOKING FOR" required placeholder="Enter user name"
    oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Do not type an email address here')"
    oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"  />
```

Comment: I think you should check why people *insists on typing their email* on that field. Maybe a UX flaw or something.

Comment: *I have an user input as "text"* — No, you don't. The only inputs you have are `email` and `submit`.

Comment: @Quentin what about <input type="text" name="dd"> ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown It is not a UX flaw actually. This is a 3rd part integration. That 3rd party uses 'username' for login but for our website they login with an email address. It is kind of difficult to explain.

Comment: @SNaRe that kind of is the definition of a UX flaw... your users are used to loging in with an email, so when presented with "login" they enter their email.  It needs to be clear what the login is / for / should be (user name).

Comment: @DarkBee Please check my edit. I added the actual code. I just need the pattern.

Comment: Entering a username for a third party site sounds like a really bad idea anyway. Using OAuth would amost certainly be a better, safer approach.

Comment: The problem here is the usernames can have any characters and character pattern in them. So potentially there could be a username which might resemble an email address pattern so if you prevent users from typing email patterns then they might not be able to enter their username.

Comment: @AmitDas — Possibly. Part of the problem is that we know nothing about the rules the other site is imposing on usernames. Perhaps "No @s" is all that is needed.

Comment: @freedomn-m You may be right but I tried couple of times. Somehow they love to type email address rather than username. I have dual login, with the username of 3rd party and email. Anyway this is not a UX post, but thanks for your warning.

Comment: So: you're saying that the login to the 3rd party system *could* be an email and you want to block emails from being used to login to the 3rd party system - *then how are they supposed to login?*  They won't be able to.  Your solution is a social engineering one, not a technical regex to block them.

Comment: Off topic: regex to validate emails is notoriously difficult (the current "standard" one is about 600 characters) - eg your validate allows 'example@example..com' (an invalid email) but doesn't allow 'Example@example.com` (a valid one).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, using HTML5's input patterns.

```
<input type="text" 
       name="username" 
       pattern="^[^@]+$">
```

That says "Don't let the form submit if there is an `@` anywhere in the text."

See http://html5pattern.com/ if you'd like to test it out.

Answer (score -3):

HTML Input Pattern attribute is used to specify the regular expression on which the input elements value is checked against .

used Regx Expression as Required By you

Answer (score -4):

**please check this pattern,might be it will help you**
`(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))`

Comment: I just need opposite of [a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$ this is way much too long.

Comment: I tested this, and it didn't complain when I entered `bob@example.com`